# Backbone views not being properly closed

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've been checking out my app in Chrome's dev tools and I noticed that there are some Detached DOM tree elements when openRace fires. What seems to be happening is it's updating the URL and creating a new view without removing/destroying the current PageView.

I have currently omitted `this.remove()` in main.js because I wanted to retain the `#content` element for the other views to attach to.

After you click a `.card` element in PageView you are taken to a new page, but in the console I get an error about GET localhost:8000/api-scrapers/data/race-index-RACE.json 404 (File not found) which tells me there are still events trying to fire on the previous view.

main.js

```
require([
'app',

], function(App){

Backbone.View.prototype.close = function() {
    console.log("close called")
    if (this.onClose) {
        this.onClose();
    }
    this.undelegateEvents();
    this.off();
};

App.init();

});
```

pageView.js

```
var PageView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: '#content',
        template: _.template(stateTemplate),

        events: {
            'click .card' : 'openRace'
        },

        initialize: function() {

            this.collection = new CollectionRacesState([]);
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.renderView);
            this.children = [];
            this.updateCollection()

        },

        updateCollection: function() {
            // console.log("updating collection...")
            var url = this.helper.getURL()
            this.collection.url = this.settings.get("defaultUrl") + 'race-index-' + (url[0]).toUpperCase() +'.json'
            this.collection.fetch({
                async: false,
                reset: true
            })
            // console.log(this.collection)
        },

        close: function() {

            console.log("closing PageState")

            // destroys children!!!
            _.each(this.views, function(view){
                view.undelegateEvents();
                view.remove();
                view.off();
            })

        },

        openRace: function(e) {
            console.log("opening race")

            var filename = $(e.currentTarget).attr("data-filename")
            Backbone.history.navigate("#/race/" + filename);

            this.close()
        },

    });

    return PageView

});
```

Answer (score 0):

if retaining `'#content'` is the problem, don't add `el` to `PageView`, while rendering render and append view el to `#content` like this.

```
var pageView = new PageView();
pageView.render();
pageView.$el.appendTo($('#content'));
```

By this remove will not remove the #content element, and can be used for other views. I normally avoid using `el` for the same reason.